# Synonym for a conclusion

Tags: synonyms, science

I'm currently writing a scientific article and thus, I need to be very careful with my English.

In this article I usually show graphics and describe them:

> "Fig. X show the temperature variation...".

Then, I write my conclusions with:

> "It can be seen that/It is shown that the temperature fluctuates..."

However, I am using these expressions way too often, so I need some sort of a synonym for them.

Since I'm not a native speaker, can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

"From what is said above..." 
"As a result,..."
"The sequel to..."
"In conclusion..."
"To conclude..."
"The outcome of this/that..."

Comment: I think OP is asking for a synonym for “variation” or “fluctuation” that he can use in his conclusion.  The title is misleading.

Comment: No no, Sardi Kuka got it right.

Comment: +1 Also, 'To summarise...' could work